# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException

Tags: ios, objective-c, iboutlet, lldb

I am coding some dummy apps to get an understanding for iOS this one such app is a TODO list. I get the following error when I click the button to add a new task.

```
2013-06-20 09:56:00.763 SnapTask[2322:11303] Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<SLAddTaskViewController 0x917fb90> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key email.'
First throw call stack:
(0x1c92012 0x10cfe7e 0x1d1afb1 0xb7c711 0xafdec8 0xafd9b7 0xb28428 0x2340cc 0x10e3663 0x1c8d45a 0x232bcf 0xf7e37 0xf8418 0x24634e 0xf8648 0xf8882 0xf8b2a 0x10fef5 0x10ffdb 0x110286 0x110381 0x110eab 0x110fc9 0x10e225 0x126082 0x12613a 0x3050e6 0xd6cba 0xd7ae8 0x304f44 0x3044eb 0x1014f3 0x101777 0x1017b7 0x46cfe2 0x45ead9 0x45eb54 0x10e3705 0x1a920 0x256b24 0x10e3705 0x1a920 0x1a8b8 0xdb671 0xdbbcf 0xdad38 0x4a33f 0x4a552 0x283aa 0x19cf8 0x1beddf9 0x1bedad0 0x1c07bf5 0x1c07962 0x1c38bb6 0x1c37f44 0x1c37e1b 0x1bec7e3 0x1bec668 0x1765c 0x24ad 0x23d5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

I have no idea where to even start, the list stores names emails and etc when adding a task

This is my `AddTaskViewController` header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class TaskListViewController;

@interface AddTaskViewController : UITableViewController

-(IBAction)cancelButtonPressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITextView *nameField;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITextView *emailField;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITextView *homeField;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITextView *cellField;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITextView *addressField;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITextView *notesField;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITextView *dateField;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet TaskListViewController * taskListViewController;

@end
```

Thank you I am so confused :(

Comment: Did you refactor your code? Was there any component with name of email? Check your connections for any invalid values.

Comment: It seems to me that you just dumped the error message into SO without having read and attempted to solve it beforehands. That's no cool.

Comment: Look at the long list of existing duplicate questions before posting such a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have changed your IBOutlet Name email to emailField.So you need to reconnect your IBOutlet in your xib.So please click on File's Owners control+left click at that time you will see different color on your connectivity.So reconnect you IBOutlet.

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Go you your IB and then check your all IBOutlets

Answer (score 0):

Try reconnecting all your `UIElement`s in that class.